# Dependency tasks graph: neat parallel execution in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Does there is an elegant ways in .Net to execute, in multithread, a graph of commands where each command can be executed only after all its parents have been executed?

For example, Visual Studio do this kind of computation while compiling a Solution in multithreading (each project can be compiled once all its dependencies have been compiled).

Another example could be if you want to clone (or load) a full database, table by table without breaking relations constraints, starting by top parents tables, then doing child tables. (It assume it exists at least one topological sort of the tables).

System.Threading.Tasks.Task seems to handle the case of chain of command with 'task.ContinueWith()', but it seem it do not threat the case of a graph of commands.

Trying to use Task with 'Task.WaitAll(dependencies)' at the start of the task process works. But it is not efficient since it begin to start the firsts task (that may wait) instead of starting the task that are ready. Here the code I used to check it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ParallelProcessing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// There is the exemple Dependency graph:
    /// 
    /// MyTypedDataSet (long job)         MyTools                   
    ///  ^                   ^             ^   ^                       
    ///  |- Project 0        |             |   |- MyControls           
    ///  ...                 |             |                 
    ///  |- Project 99       |- MyForm ----|
    ///           
    /// 
    /// 'MyControls' should compile quickly after MyTools. Instead of that, MyControls is flooded by Project 0..99
    /// </summary>
    public class TestTasks
    {
        public static void Trace(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[" + Task.CurrentId + "] " + message);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss.fff") + " [" + Task.CurrentId + "] " + message);
        }
        private static void compile(string projectName, int duration, params Task[] dependency)
        {
            Task.WaitAll(dependency);
            TestTasks.Trace("Start compiling " + projectName);
            Thread.Sleep(duration);
            TestTasks.Trace("End compiling " + projectName);
        }

        public static void RunTest()
        {
            Task taskMyTypedDataSet = new Task(() => TestTasks.compile("MyTypedDataSet", 10000));
            taskMyTypedDataSet.Start();

            Task taskMyTools = new Task(() => TestTasks.compile("MyTools", 2000));
            taskMyTools.Start();

            List<Task> lotOfOtherProjets = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                string projectName = "Project" + i;
                Task task = new Task(() => TestTasks.compile(projectName, 100, taskMyTypedDataSet));
                task.Start();
                lotOfOtherProjets.Add(task);
            }
            Task taskMyControls = new Task(() => TestTasks.compile("MyControls", 100, taskMyTools));
            taskMyControls.Start();

            Task taskMyForms = new Task(() => TestTasks.compile("MyForms", 100, taskMyControls, taskMyTypedDataSet));
            taskMyForms.Start();

            Task.WaitAll(taskMyTypedDataSet, taskMyForms);
            Task.WaitAll(lotOfOtherProjets.ToArray());
            TestTasks.Trace("Process done");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Do you know if there is a neat solution for this kind of problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321258.aspx) for this.

For example:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { /* some computation */ });
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { /* another computation */ });
var continuationTask = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
    new[] { task1, task2 }, tasks => { /* dependent computation */ });
```

In .Net 4.5, [`Task.WhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does something very similar.

Answer (score 1):

I will double check this, but I believe that if you spin up tasks within tasks, then the parent will not be considered complete until all of the children are complete. So, why not just call tasks within tasks for this kind of graph?

[Here is the MSDN article elaborating more on this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx). This does sound like exactly what you want.

From the article:

> You can use attached child tasks to create tightly-synchronized graphs
>   of asynchronous operations

UPDATE to encompass comment from @DrewMarsh/MSDN article:

You will need to make sure to specify the TaskCreationOptions->TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent or else the nest task will be detached.

Comment: This is true as long as you specify the TaskCreationOptions|TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent flag. Works like a charm and great for coordinated workflows of Tasks.

Comment: @DrewMarsh Thanks, I have added this into my answer. It is in the MSDN article, but it is better to put that here.

Comment: As far as I can see, it allow to create tightly-synchronized **tree** of asynchronous operations. It do not allow 2 parents to share a same child task.